# links estão deixando espaço

Tags: html, css

Estava modificando minha barra fixa do meu site, e me ocorreu algo que não consigo consertar: tenho 1 `nav` que dentro tem 1 `ul` que dentro tem 4 `li`s e dentro de cada `li` tem um `a`, o que ocorre é que estou deixando a seguinte propriedade para os `li`s para que ocupem 25% do tamanho da `nav`(ou do `ul` , não tenho certeza,mas é irrelevante já que ambos tem o mesmo tamanho e seus `padding`s = 0), mas quando a regra é aplicada o último item da lista não se encaixa na mesma linha e pula pra outra,o que não quero que aconteça.
Aqui esta o código relevante:

```
            <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicos.html">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="fotos.html">FOTOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="contato.html">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        /*CSS em arquivo separado*/

* {box-sizing:border-box;}

nav#menu {
position        : fixed;
top             : 0;
width           : 320px;
left            : 0;
z-index         : 10;

}

nav#menu ul {
padding         : 0;
z-index         : 10;
background-color: #DCDCDC;
list-style      : none;
margin          : 0;
left            : 0;
right           : 0;
}

nav#menu ul li {
background-color:#DCDCDC;   
display            : inline-block;
width: 25%;
padding            : 4px;
font-family        : 'Titillium Web';
font-size          : 10pt;
text-align         : center;
}

nav#menu ul li.active {
background-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom   : solid 2px rgb(200,20,20);
background-image: none;
color           : rgb(200,20,20);
}

nav#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color          : #393939;
    word-spacing   : 0;
}
```

O que percebi é que se você clicar e arrastar o mouse como se estivesse selecionando um texto além de selecionar o conteúdo dentro do `a` também é selecionado espaços em branco entre os `li`s.

Comment: Tente adicionar no "nav#menu ul li" a propriedade "float: left;". Se não der, coloque o tamanho em pixels para ver como eles se comportam. Vale também colocar "padding: 0px;" no "nav#menu"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode definir o tamanho das li com `80px` e a nav com `width:auto`.

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}

nav#menu {
position        : fixed;
top             : 0;
width           : auto;
left            : 0;
z-index         : 10;

}

nav#menu ul {
padding         : 0;
z-index         : 10;
background-color: #DCDCDC;
list-style      : none;
margin          : 0;
left            : 0;
right           : 0;
}

nav#menu ul li {
background-color:#DCDCDC;   
display            : inline-block;
width:80px;
padding            : 4px;
font-family        : 'Titillium Web';
font-size          : 10pt;
text-align         : center;
}

nav#menu ul li.active {
background-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom   : solid 2px rgb(200,20,20);
background-image: none;
color           : rgb(200,20,20);
}

nav#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color          : #393939;
    word-spacing   : 0;
}
```

```html
            <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicos.html">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="fotos.html">FOTOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="contato.html">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```